# JasperReports, export to docx - footer formatting

Tags: java, templates, jasper-reports, footer, docx

I am new to *JasperReports*.

How can I make word document more user friendly with *JasperReports*?

I create simple document, and convert in *docx*.

Footer still not have absolute position. If you focus in content and insert new column above/below,
the footer will move to the next page.

How to create static/absolute footer in *JR* report? (*.docx* extension report)

Comment: What footer (band) do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Jasper Reports uses tables to render docx format, if you select all your document and enable all cells boundaries you'll note each page is a table.

http://www.smartjava.org/content/create-complex-word-docx-documents-programatically-docx4j

Probably you'll need to read an excel file and fill into a docx with programatically with docx4j library in order to mantain header and footer in a word template.